# How to correctly segue from one view to another on button press programatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uibutton

I would like to hook up this to a UIButton programatically (which is inside a stackView), so pressing it will navigate to theCCController.

```
UIButton *ccbutton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
[ccbutton setTitle:@"CC" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[ccbutton addTarget:self action:@selector(ccPage) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

my ccPage method is giving me troubles though, I am a bit of a beginner and have not been able to figure out how to solve my issue, I believe I need to use performSegueWithIdentifier but I havent found success with it (or other alternatives).

The ones I have commented out do not work on their own, and i think from other similar questions ive read i need to do a function override, but im really not sure what I'm supposed to add where from their descriptions. Could anyone give me a hand, I would greatly appreciate it as I feel very lost

```
-(void)ccPage {
  //[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ccPageLinkCell" sender:self];
  //[self presentViewController:@"ccPageLinkCell" animated: TRUE, completion:nil];
  //[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"theCCController" sender:self];
  //[self presentViewController:@"theCCController" animated: TRUE, completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: You say you can navigate *"using a linkcell"* ... What is a "linkcell"? Is it what you've named the cells in a TableView? If so, do you have a `segue` defined that is triggered when that cell is selected? If so, you can give that `segue` an identifier - such as `gotoTheCCController` -
 and then in your button tap action, call `[ self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"gotoTheCCController" sender: nil)];`

Comment: @donmag i meant to type PSLinkCell sorry tried clarifying, i dont have any segues defined but ill look into that

Comment: You say *" I am able to navigate there using a PSLinkCell"* ... If you don't have any segues defined, how is "PSLinkCell" navigating you there?

Comment: @DonMag to my understanding its this part, i dont have anything other than what Ive posted, it just happens to work this way but I hoped to figure out how to do it without them https://ghostbin.com/paste/c6zkt

Comment: Sorry - is this part of a 3rd-party library? Searching apple.com for PSLinkCell returns nothing.

Comment: @DonMag does this link help? like i said i dont have any segues myself so i basically am starting from nothing, http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Preferences_specifier_plist#PSLinkCell

Comment: Ah - the first line on the "main page" at that link is: *"Our goal is to share the sum of all human[1] knowledge about **jailbroken** iOS development."* I've never even ***looked*** at anything related to *jailbreaking*.

Comment: @DonMag that would explain why it is foreign to you, but it does not limit your ability to help, as i think its common in app development (which i dont do enough of so im struggling). I wanted to post it so people could see how little i have in regards to getting the non-PSLinkCell solution . many explanations ive found on this matter all make use of xcode / storyboards which i have never used unfortunately so i need help with a pure objc solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143033/discussion-between-donmag-and-user286152).